# Mockito Scala Specs2 mocking complex functions (Play Framework)

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I'm trying to properly stub the ehCache API used by Play Framework. In particular, its getOrElse function with signature:

```
def getOrElse[A: ClassTag](key: String, expiration: Duration)(orElse: => A)
```

Within my specs 2 code, I have:

```
val mockCache = mock[EhCacheApi]
mockCache.getOrElse[???](anyString,anyObject[Duration])(???) returns 
[Object I'd like returned]
```

Question is if it's possible to use matchers for the ??? parts, especially for the currying argument part.

The return type for the CacheApi function should be Future[Seq[Object]] .

Public git repo link: [Github](https://github.com/zhangcbrian/specs2-mockito-so-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
class VariationAssignmentSpec(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {

  case class Variation(id: Option[Long] = None)

  lazy val v1 = Variation(Option(1L))
  lazy val v2 = Variation(Option(2L))

  "Cache#getOrElse" should {
    "return correct result" in {

      val mockCache = mock[CacheApi]

      mockCache.getOrElse[Future[Seq[Variation]]](anyString, any[Duration])(any)(any) returns
        Future(Seq(v1, v2))

      val resultFuture: Future[Seq[Variation]] =
        mockCache.getOrElse("cache.key", 10.seconds)(Future(Seq(v1,v2)))

      resultFuture must equalTo(Seq(v1,v2)).await
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting "missing argument for method apply in object Future, follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function" , and my mock line looks like this: mockCache.getOrElse[Future[Seq[Variation]]](anyString, any[Duration])(===(Future[Seq[Variation]])) returns Future(Seq(v1,v2))

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what "A" should be for getOrElse[A] .

Comment: Sorry I forgot to pass the `orElse` parameter. I hope this works because byname parameters are a bit tricky with Mockito.

Comment: If that still doesn't work and your project is public please post the link to your repo.

Comment: still not quite working, it compiles but still fails in test. It's not a public repo but I'll create a public one with trimmed down code and link it here, thank you so much in advance

Comment: Thanks for the project, this really helps.

Comment: I'm getting : org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
-> at org.specs2.mock.mockito.MockitoMatchers$class.anyString(MockitoMatchers.scala:14)
-> at org.specs2.mock.mockito.MockitoMatchers$class.any(MockitoMatchers.scala:45)
-> at org.specs2.mock.mockito.MockitoMatchers$class.any(MockitoMatchers.scala:45),

Comment: This works for me: https://github.com/zhangcbrian/specs2-mockito-so-example/pull/1

Comment: It works great for me as well in sbt, but somehow fails in IntelliJ, seems like an IntelliJ problem then, thank you so much!

Comment: One more question, why is there a second (any), what does that match? @Eric

Comment: The second `any` matches the implicit `ClassTag`.